# Issue while using between operator in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

where location between 'G1' and 'G4'.

While using this in the end of my query the result showing is :-

```
G11
G12
G13
G14
G2
G3
G1
G4
```

I only want locations as G1,G2,G3,G4 and does not need `G11,G12` etc.
Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Tag RDBMS which you are using ?

Comment: Because your field is a string type and G2 comes after G1X. Your solution depends on the data you have in this field, are there other characters than `G`?

Comment: I understand that G2 comes after G1X but is there any alternative to prevent this.
No there is no other characters than G

Comment: You'd need to parse the field and the strings.  If we assume that all strings always begin with a G and otherwise have only numeric characters, `where substr(location,2,length(location)) between substr('G1',2,length('G1')) and substr('G4',2,length('G4'))` would work.  You'd probably need a function-based index to make that perform reasonably.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but there are other locations also in which there is no numeric value and have only characters whose length is also not fixed (some are 5 char long.some are 6 char long).

Comment: Well, that comment solved the problem for the data set you provided. If you have additional requirements, you should provide us with the full list of possible values, and also, how the usage of 'between' should make sense on those.

Comment: locations are (G1,G2,G3,G01,G02,G11,G12,G21,G31, 'STAGE','PICK','A01','A02,'BULK'' etc)

Answer (score 1):

For filter query based on a range  of string  (adn not other filter are useful) a proper way is use a in clause  eg:

```
select * from my_table
where my_column in ('G1', G2, 'G3', G4, 'GX5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below where clause :

```
where substr(Col_name,2,length(Col_name)) between 'G1' and 'G4'
```